# JasperReports and Microsoft Word - justified text align

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-word

I have jrxml report, which gets exported into .docx format, 
I have static text resources (.properties) with `"\n" or "<br>"` signs in values, like so:
[image]

In jasperreports 'preview' tab it looks ok:

[image]

But when .docx format is used...:

[image]

I figured out that when you paste [image: pilcrow] pilcrow/paragraph (by pressing `enter` key) in word itself,

justified alignment [image] works ok,

but with `<br>` or `\n` jasper inserts [image] new line (`shift enter` equivalent) and it breaks everything.

May be someone knows what could be done.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution:

To brake row I use `tab/newline` (`&#9;<br>` via HTML or `\t\n` via Java),

Text *before* `tab/newline` is aligned to the left border, text after is still justified well along the page.

[image]